# Can I force my Google-Play beta-test users to use the stable app?

Tags: android, testing, google-play

I plan to use the Google-Play alpha/beta-testing feature for my Android app, before releasing it to the public.

However, after publishing a "stable" app, can I force my beta testers to use that version instead of the beta, or do they all need to opt-out from the testing?

And when the public version can be automatically installed on their devices, will they be able to rate the app afterwards (that is not possible using a beta app)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question:

If I upload a new version as productive, my beta testers will get that too. They can rate the app if they have got a productive version installed. When I upload a new version as beta then, only the beta-testers will get that update (as expected).

Comment: Did you happen to find any docs from Google that explain this? Just curious. Thanks for the answer, btw!

Comment: @Dave: No I did not find any documentation about this, I tried it myself after I released the first stable version of my app.

Comment: @DaveJensen We have Released our App and my beta testers are updating App too but they are unable to rate the app as they still seen you are a beta tester for the App, if you can help what to be done ?